# Angular 2 using a CSS hook as a selector

Tags: angular

New to Angular 2  and currently trying to build a site with it. I have, however, run into a problem relating to component decorator "selector". If I use a custom tag, eg 'my-tag' then it works but if I use a css selector, eg '#myId', then it doesn't.

this doesn't work;

```
@Component({
    selector: '#siteNav',
    templateUrl: ...
})
```

this does work

```
@Component({
    selector: 'site-nav',
    templateUrl: ...
})
```

Is there something obvious I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#someId` is not supported.

Use instead

```
selector: '[id=siteNav]'
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11885

Comment: Thank you , that does work. However it's inconsistent because the "#header" selector works for parent component.

Comment: I guess you mean the root component? You are right, it's a bit inconsistent.